# How to make div width and height 100% while printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have a fullcalendar.js implemented on my page,but i cant print the calendar covering full page.
Here is my html

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width = 25% > hello </td>
      <td> <div id='calendar'></div></td>
   </tr>
</table> </body>
```

Now if I try to print this I m getting a blank space on left here is my style.

```
<style>
    @media print {
    body * {
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    #calendar,
    #calendar * {
    visibility: visible;
    }

    }
```

So how to print just a div #calendar covering full page 
here is my implementation http://plnkr.co/edit/SsYdQn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try @page declaration.

Add the following style rule to the page. It removes all blank spaces on the all sides.

```
<style type='text/css'>
@page{margin:0;size:auto}
</style>
```